# Javascript recursive

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

i have this problem i want to create a recursive function for calculate all possibilities to have a number (k>0), with the addition of number 1 or 2. Example for the number 2 i have two poss. 2 = 1+1 and 2 = 2 , for number 3 two poss. 3 = 1+1+1 or 3 = 1+2. I have this idea, but doesn't work ..

```
function op(k, n, i) {
    if (n == k) {
        return i++;
    } else if (n > k) {
        return i;
    } else {
        n = n + 1;
        op(k, n, i);
        n = n + 2;
        op(k, n, i);
    }
}

op(3, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `else` block.

Comment: primitive types are passed-by-value in function parameters in javascript

Comment: And you're not doing anything with the return value from the calls to op() in the else block.

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: it's wrong in my case, but expected results for k=3 is 2

Comment: You want to get all the possibilities where the sum of two numbers results in the number that you provided? 3 = 3 + 0; 0 + 3; 1 + 2; 2 + 1 (4 possibilities)

Comment: no only use number, two and one.... for example if k=5 then i can obtain 5 in three different ways : 5 = 2+2+1 or 5 = 2+1+1+1 or 5=1+1+1+1+1 ... i want this number of combination for input 5 output is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are looking to do this recursively. More explanation would have helped from that angle. If you are trying to get back the number of times a value k can be added using 1's and 2's, then simply take the base case (1+1+1+...k times), and add the specific case where 1's are grouped (1+1+1+(1+1)) and that is your answer.

```js
function op(k){
 return 1 + parseInt(k/2,10);
}
for(var i = 1;i < 100; i++){ console.log(i+": "+op(i)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last block, the recursion step, should look like this:

```
} else {
    return op(k, n+1, i) + op(k, n+2, i);
}
```

You call the function for adding 1, call it again for adding 2, and then add those two together.

You'll work faster with **memoization**: store the results for a given configuration, so you don't have to repeat calculations for numbers you've aready done.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just:

```
function combinations(n) {
    return 1 + (Math.floor(n/2)); 
};
```

Or am I very wrong here?
You have the base 1xn case n = (1+1+1+1...)
Then you can group all the 1's, e.g n = ((1+1)+1+1+1...)
So you wind up with this generic function.

For every two 1's in there, there's just one more permutation. This seems to hold true for odds and evens. If I've made a mistake someone let me know!

Edit: Someone already solved above, didn't notice! Nice work! Upvoted you!